# QGIS Maptips - images not oriented correctly

Tags: qgis, maptips

I have a Map Tip in QGIS for a points layer. I'm using the following HTML to display images from my Mac:

```html
<div style="width:400;height:400">
    <p>[% "name" %]</p>
    [% CASE
        WHEN "photo_name" IS NOT NULL
            THEN '<div><img src="file:///path/to/images/' || "photo_name" || '" width="350"/></div>'
        ELSE 'No picture available'
    END %]
</div>
```

The code works, but the images are often rotated 90 or 180 degrees in the Map Tip from their actual orientation on my computer and iPhone. There are, however, many cases where the images **are** oriented properly on the Map Tip. The issue happens sporadically.

---

For example, the following image is oriented correctly on my computer:

[image]

But QGIS displays it like this:

[image]

I've seen [this GitHub issue on the QGIS repo](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34868), but it didn't clear things up.

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: have you tried to use css for the orientation? <div style="width:400;height:400;image-orientation: from-image;">

Comment: Same result if I add the `image-orientation` argument.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a better way but here is my current workaround:

- Added a field to my attribute table called `rotation`. Default value is 0, but if an image needs to be rotated, I add 90, 180 etc to the field for that point.
- Rotated images often overlap with the title (`"name"`), so I also added `style="padding-bottom: 30px;`

```html
<div style="width:500;height:500;">
    <p style="padding-bottom: 30px;">[% "name" %]</p>
    [% CASE
        WHEN "link1_href" IS NOT NULL
            THEN '<div><img src="file:///path/to/file' || 
            "link1_href" || 
            '" width="350" style="transform:rotate(' || 
            "rotation" || 
            'deg);"/></div>'
        ELSE
            'No picture available'
    END %]
</div>
```

###### Photo from question (with a `rotation` value of 180 added to attribute table):

[image]

Comment: you can also use the "Import geotagged photos" algorithm to automatically read the rotation values from the exif data if the photos contain these information: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#import-geotagged-photos